# phprestsql configuration problems

Tags: php, mysql, rest, ini, restful-architecture

I 've been trying to set up a REST interface for a database by using phprestsql, however although I am able to log in and view the database tables when I am trying to view any of their contents I get the following result:

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404

The contents of my phprestsql.ini are the following:

```
[settings]
baseURL = "/rest"
[database]
type = "mysql"

server = "localhost:3306"
database = "onthespotpersonnel"

foreignKeyPostfix = "_uid"

[renderers]
text/xml = xml.php
text/plain = plain.php
text/html = html.php

[mimetypes]
xml = text/xml
txt = text/plain
html = text/html
```

While the .htaccess.example contains the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
    #RewriteRule ^.*$ /rest/index.php
```

I am quite new to this kind of stuff so, any proposed ideas are welcome :)

**p.s** when I insert the 3306 port to table content links (e.g http://172.16.2.2:3306/rest/device) the following message appears:

```
J���
5.5.21�x��T[OXN[aU�ÿ÷�€����������f!l"]4'gQ@.c�mysql_native_password�
```

I believe that it is not an encoding error since the characters appear in the source of the html document as well...

Comment: You need to rename your .htaccess.example to .htaccess and make sure that your rewrite rule is pointing to the folder where index.php is (in your case it seems to be /rest/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql_native_password from the error message is from the MySQL client connections port. You are trying to connect to the MySQL service directly. phprestsql runs from the web server and accesses the database itself. You may access phprestsql over the standard http port (80) with your web browser.

Try the following as your configuration. Enter the user name and password for the database, then connect to `http://172.16.2.2/rest/`

```
[settings]
baseURL = "/rest"

[database]
type = "mysql"
server = "localhost"
database = "onthespotpersonnel"
username = ""
password = ""
foreignKeyPostfix = "_uid"

[renderers]
text/xml = xml.php
text/plain = plain.php
text/html = html.php

[mimetypes]
xml = text/xml
txt = text/plain
html = text/html
```